# How to add ApplicationInsights Logging Provider in Framework Console App Using Autofac

Tags: .net-core, autofac, azure-application-insights

I am working on a .NET (full framework 4.7.1) console app that uses AutoFac for DI purposes.

We are in the process of migrating slowly to .NET Core, and have switched to using the ILogger abstractions provided by Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.

I have wired up ILogger<> and ILoggerFactory in AutoFac using the following

```
        private static void RegisterLogging(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.RegisterType<LoggerFactory>().As<ILoggerFactory>().SingleInstance();
            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Logger<>)).As(typeof(ILogger<>)).InstancePerDependency();
        }
```

This depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging - and it seems to be working.

Now I want to wire up the Application Insights Logging provider, however all the documentation I can find only mentions how to add it to the .NET Core DI Container, and looking through the source code on various repos, I am a bit mystified on how to do it.

I figured that I might be able to do it like this:
`builder.RegisterType<ApplicationInsightsLoggerProvider>().As<ILoggerProvider>();`

But it depends on `IOptions<TelemetryConfiguration> telemetryConfigurationOptions` and  `IOptions<ApplicationInsightsLoggerOptions> applicationInsightsLoggerOptions` neither of which I have.

Have anybody done this, or have suggestions on how to accomplish it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get something going by doing it like this:

```
var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
serviceCollection.AddLogging();
serviceCollection.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
builder.Populate(serviceCollection);
```

Not the very best solution, but I guess it does allow me to use the footwork of the ServiceCollection extensions methods, so I might have to live with that if nobdoy has a better answer